# Faster way than .csv to upload data into Django app

Tags: javascript, python, django, csv

Right now I copy a whole table from a website, paste it into a cell on an excel spreadsheet and it formats it into a .csv file.

After the .csv is made I upload the file into my database via a Django app.

I also have a model form if I wanted to enter the data manually.

What I was wondering is if there is a way to skip a step to make the process faster. Maybe copy the table from the web and paste it into a form cell and it gets formatted like excel does.

Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using pandas, you can try something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df = pd.read_clipboard()  # table was copied to clipboard from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
df.to_sql("mytable", conn)
pd.read_sql("select * from mytable", conn)

df.to_csv("mytable.csv")  # if CSV is needed
```